# iPhone Core data - Not constant path between entities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data, entity-relationship

I have an entity which has relationships with other entities. Let say we have: user->menu->meal

My problem is that some of the users don't have a menu. So when I try to check: user.menu.meal == rice I get an error (path not found...)!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a nil check on the relationship then...

```
if (user.menu != nil && user.menu.meal != nil)
```

Or even better, define a helper method that will return the meal if it's present...

```
mealForUser:(User*)someUser {
     if (user.menu != nil && user.menu.meal != nil)
     return user.menu.meal;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have some to many relationships and can't check each of the menus and meals... don't you have a better solution to implement IN the NSPredicate?

Comment: You can perform similar checks in your NSPredicate.  If you have a FetchRequest for the entity user then you can specify a NSPredicate as follows...
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(menu != nil) AND (menu.meal != nil)"];

Comment: Ok but let say some of my users have menus and some of these menus have meals. How would you do with these 'one to many' relationships?

Comment: To deal with one-to-many relationships you can use....

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(menu != nil) AND (menu.meals@count > 0)"]

Comment: That is a lot of dancing just to use dot syntax when a simple KVC call will work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check this in code as:

```
if (![user valueForKeyPath:@"menu.meal"]) {
 //User does not have a menu or a meal
}
```

Inside of your predicate it would look the same:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.menu.meal == nil"]
```

In either case, because nil is handled gracefully in Objective-C you will get the right answer.